# Optional attachment in java mail

Tags: java, spring, email, attachment

I want to do optional file attachment. Now I have this code:

```
public void prepareAndSend(String subject, String messageContent, String recipient,
                           String attachmentFileName, InputStreamSource attachmentFile)
        throws MessagingException {
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
    messageHelper.setTo(recipient);
    messageHelper.setSubject(subject);
    messageHelper.setText(messageContent);
    messageHelper.addAttachment(attachmentFileName, attachmentFile);
    mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
}
```

I was thinking about second method with only 3 arguments:

```
public void prepareAndSend(String subject, String messageContent, String recipient)
```

Sembody have maybe idea how can I split this code to avoid CTRL+C, CTRL+V? I was thinking about something like:

```
public void prepareAndSend(String subject, String messageContent, String recipient)
        throws MessagingException {
    prepareAndSend(subject, messageContent, recipient, null, null);
}

public void prepareAndSend(String subject, String messageContent, String recipient,
                           String attachmentFileName, InputStreamSource attachmentFile)
        throws MessagingException {
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
    messageHelper.setTo(recipient);
    messageHelper.setSubject(subject);
    messageHelper.setText(messageContent);
    if (attachmentFileName == null) {
        messageHelper.addAttachment(attachmentFileName, attachmentFile);
    }
    mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
}
```

But it wasn't working.

Comment: Why it (last code) wasn't working? Any error you could add to your question? Also, your `if (attachmentFileName == null) {
        messageHelper.addAttachment(attachmentFileName, attachmentFile);
    }` is odd because you add the attatchment if the variable is null.

Comment: OMG, thanks. I made so stupid mistake.